# Spring Losing Security Context during Testing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot integration test like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("Test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class HelloControllerIT {
    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        HttpEntity request = //buildJson;
        ResponseEntity response = template.exchange("/put", HttpMethod.PUT, request, Object.class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

When the template sends the request, there's a point in my code that looks like this:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
```

Here's what the context looks like this:
[image]

I need to set the security context so that it's not anonymous. I can do it like this:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
context.setAuthentication(authResult);
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

But when I try to do that before `template.exchange` I still get anonymousUser. I've tried this:

```
template.withBasicAuth("User","pass");
```

It still doesn't work. How do I set the `TestRestTemplate` security context?

Comment: You probably need the `@EnableWebSecurity` and `@WithMockUser` annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to create a class that implements `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and then set the context there. This was you can avoid any sort of mocking which I was keen on doing to make this a more ETE integration test. Here's that class

```
public class TestSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().securityContext().securityContextRepository(new TestSecurityContextRepository());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `TestSecurityContextRepository`? I only find a private class that I cannot use.